# Appcelerator Studio - App crashes due to memory leak

Tags: appcelerator

I currently have a window that uses a view for a navigation view type purpose. In that navigation view, I have an array of views that are added in as well. Just recently, I've been getting a Out of memory error on the Galaxy S4.

```
[WARN] :   TiUIScrollView: (main) [1647,1647] Scroll direction could not be determined based on the provided view properties. Default VERTICAL scroll direction being used. Use the 'scrollType' property to explicitly set the scrolling direction.
[WARN] :   TiUIScrollView: (main) [173,1820] Scroll direction could not be determined based on the provided view properties. Default VERTICAL scroll direction being used. Use the 'scrollType' property to explicitly set the scrolling direction.
[WARN] :   TiUIScrollView: (main) [240,2060] Scroll direction could not be determined based on the provided view properties. Default VERTICAL scroll direction being used. Use the 'scrollType' property to explicitly set the scrolling direction.
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 135MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 27.099ms for cause Alloc
[INFO] :   art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 793us total 8.819ms
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(528B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 793us total 25.634ms
[INFO] :   art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 32.867ms for cause Background
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 57(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 701us total 39.062ms
[INFO] :   art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1101KB allocation
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 59(2504B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 549us total 33.752ms
[ERROR] :  art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1128396 byte allocation with 278738 free bytes and 272KB until OOM"
[ERROR] :  TiUIHelper: (main) [525,2585] Unable to load bitmap. Not enough memory: Failed to allocate a 1128396 byte allocation with 278738 free bytes and 272KB until OOM
[INFO] :   art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 35(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 885us total 9.521ms
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(384B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 671us total 26.031ms
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 701us total 35.888ms
[INFO] :   art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1101KB allocation
[INFO] :   art: Clamp target GC heap from 143MB to 128MB
[INFO] :   art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 732us total 38.513ms
[ERROR] :  art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1128396 byte allocation with 278258 free bytes and 271KB until OOM"
[ERROR] :  TiUIHelper: (main) [121,2706] Unable to load bitmap. Not enough memory: Failed to allocate a 1128396 byte allocation with 278258 free bytes and 271KB until OOM
[INFO] :   art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 235(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 127MB/128MB, paused 732us total 6.988ms
```

I can see it creating views, but it crashes. I have around 40-50 views. I'm trying to figure a way to combat this problem. Anyone have some tips, or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, fixed it! Downsized some of my images!

Comment: Just a tip: When you want images in scroll view - first of all use TableView or ListView. And load your images in an ImageView object and not a View - That will let the platform manage the memory better for you and ImageView does bitmap loading better than a view (on android).

Comment: @developer82 Thank you for the helpful tip! Much appreciated.